# Page body content updated only after second load

Tags: 7

I want to programmatically update the HTML contents of a page (a node of bundle type 'page') on my Drupal 7 site, by doing the following:

```
function my_page_generate() {
   // Find and load the page I want to update (can't do it by nid since
   // it might differ)
   $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
   $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
   ->propertyCondition('type', 'page')
   ->propertyCondition('title', 'Last News')
   ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
   ->execute();
   $node_key = array_keys($entities['node']);
   $node = node_load($node_key[0]);

   //Update its HTML contents
   $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'] = 'full_html';
   $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = '<h1> BREAKING NEWS </h1>';

   node_save($node);

   return node_view($node, 'full');
}
```

This method is called when requesting a URL by using the hook_menu hook, like this:

```
function my_module_menu() {
   $items = array();
   $items['last-news'] = array(
    'title' => 'Last News',
    'page callback' => 'my_page_generate',
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
   );

   return $items;
}
```

However, when I navigate to /last-news on my site, the old contents of the page are displayed. If then I reload the same page again (using the same path), the new contents I created show up. I have tried to disable the page cache for this page by calling $GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE, but it keeps showing the same behavior.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7

You should clear cache programmatically if you want to use current solution or just load node again (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) after save.

Third argument of node_load must be true

Comment: Thank you, loading the node again using node_load after saving it fixed it.